# php DomDocument -- find empty text node?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

Take this very basic XML document (this is just a basic example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<books>
    <book>first title<sep/>first author</book>
    <book>second title<sep/>second author</book>
    <book>third title<sep/>third author</book>
    <book><sep/>fourth author</book>
</books>
```

The problem is pretty simple... How do I insert the title of the fourth book ?
And how do I automatically detect that the title is not set for the fourth book ?

What I'd really need is the php DOMDocument to tell me that there is an empty text node in front of the last `<sep/>`.
But with DOMDocument, the node simply does not exist:

```
<?php

$path = './books.xml';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($path);

$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');

foreach ($books as $index => $book) {
    echo $book->childNodes->length . ' children' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The code above shows only 2 childnodes for the last `book` node.

And using Xpath `/books/book[4]/text()[1]` points to the "author" text node of the fourth book and does not point to the empty text node in front of the `<sep/>`

Let me know if this is not perfectly clear...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: sidenote: `$index` is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not telling you there is an empty text node there because there isn't a text node there - that simple. The xpath expression to pick out that book would be:

```
/books/book[not(sep/preceding-sibling::text())]
```

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<books>
    <book>first title<sep/>first author</book>
    <book>second title<sep/>second author</book>
    <book>third title<sep/>third author</book>
    <book><sep/>fourth author</book>
</books>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '/books/book[not(sep/preceding-sibling::text())]';
foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $book) {
    $title = $dom->createTextNode("fourth title");
    $book->insertBefore($title, $book->firstChild);
    echo $dom->saveXML($book), "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
<book>fourth title<sep/>fourth author</book>
```

Comment: Thanks...  I got that far myself. Thing is the XML I really need to parse is far more complex and I figured there might have been a better way.